# In Rails, how to add an element to an array type attribute for all records?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

DB is PostgreSQL. How do you append a value for all records to a column that has an array data type?

For example:

```
# migration_file.rb

def change
  add_column :users, :tags, :string, array: true, default: []
end
```

How do I append the same value to the `tags` attributes to all User records? I want to do something like:

```
User.update_all(tags << "some_tag")
```

Comment: Try with this `User.update_all(tags << ['some_tag'])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass an SQL snippet to [`update_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) so you can use all the usual [PostgreSQL array operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE). For example:

```
User.update_all(['tags = tags || ?::text', 'some_tag'])
```

or without the `||` ambiguity (and corresponding cast):

```
User.update_all(['tags = array_append(tags, ?)', 'some_tag'])
User.update_all(['tags = tags || array[?]', 'some_tag'])
```

Note that you'd be passing `update_all` an array in this case, you need to do that to convince AR that you want `'some_tag'` to fill in the placeholder rather than be the WHERE clause.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, unfortunately I'm running into `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information.` The error might be unrelated to the problem at hand; I'll keep digging.

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL is this? Can you `update users set tags = tags || 'some_tag'` from `psql`?

Comment: No I can't in `psql`, even after upgrading from 9.2.2 to 9.3.4. For kicks in my migration file, I changed `default: []` to `default: '{}'` but no luck either.

Comment: OK here's what appears to be working: `update users set tags = tags || '{some_value}'`. I'm gonna tinker around a little more, but this appears to be the correct syntax.

Comment: There are two forms of `||` for arrays: `array || element` and `array || array`. I'm guessing that PostgreSQL is choosing the `array || array` form and trying to interpret the string as an array-in-string-format (i.e. it is expecting `{some_value}` which is the same as `array['some_value']`. If you add an explicit cast (as in my updated answer) then it should choose the right version of the `|| `operator. Alternatively, you could use `array_append` and avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: I was using an `int[]` while playing around with this BTW, the number avoided the ambiguity over which `||` should be used. Sorry.

Comment: Perfect! Man I learned so much about postgres. This is fantastic. Thanks for your help!